# Adding rules that aren't properties themselves in ReactiveUI.Validation

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I would like to know if a validation rule can be added to a non-property. Like this.AddRule(booleanObs). This makes sense in scenarios where the property is not exposed as a property.

Something like this:

```cs
class MyViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject 
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.ValidationRule(x => x.Name, x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(), "Name cannot be empty");
        IObservable<bool> isDatabaseReady = database.IsReady;
        this.ValidationRule(isDatabaseReady);
    }
}
```

As you see, the `isDatabaseReady` observable isn't exposed, I want it to be taken into account to determine if MyViewModel is valid.

ReactiveUI.Validation seemingly forces you to add rules that are exposed as properties and have a given error message.

NOTE: I'm only using RxUI for ViewModels (not Views) and regular bindings.

Comment: Do you want to add validation rules to fields directly? In your example `x.Name` looks like a property.

Comment: Yes, that would cover my use case. I would like to add "extra" rules that aren't based on exposed properties.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the class with the field you want to validate. Also explain why you can't use properties, since ReactiveUI is working on properties and PropertyChanged events. Show as well how you set the field value and if it is possible to fire your own PropertyChanged event (maybe for a different property). Provide a MCVE if possible.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What is the problem with using [`ValidationRule(IObservable<bool>, string)`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.extensions/validatableviewmodelextensions/e67488f4)?

Comment: The fact that it requires an error message that will never be shown makes me wonder if I'm abusing the API or not. I'm asking because there could be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ValidationRule(IObservable<bool>, string)`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.validation.extensions/validatableviewmodelextensions/e67488f4) overload to register an observable for additional validation check. When the observable returns `false`, the model becomes invalid with the specified error message. You can use it like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject 
{
    public MyViewModel(IObservable<bool> externalSource)
    {
        this.ValidationRule(externalSource, "external source is invalid");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISubject<bool> externalSource = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
        MyViewModel f = new MyViewModel(externalSource);
        f.IsValid().Subscribe(it => Console.WriteLine(it));

        externalSource.OnNext(false);
        externalSource.OnNext(true);
        externalSource.OnNext(false);
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
False
False
True
False
```